# React Native Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' during up-to-date check

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to generate a signed apk file for my react native app (via running ./gradlew assembleRelease), however I am running into the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' during up-to-date check.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mohammad/superexnews/metro-bundler-symbolicate117830-24506-1aaqyox.dr9.sock (No such device or address)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Here is it with the stacktrace option:

```
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFbuiTextlayoutbuilderTextlayoutbuilder100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp3130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0484Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' during up-to-date check.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mohammad/superexnews/metro-bundler-symbolicate117830-24506-1aaqyox.dr9.sock (No such device or address)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' during up-to-date check.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.createSnapshot(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesTaskStateChanges.getCurrent(InputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.getChanges(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges$1.<init>(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.iterator(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.InputFilesTaskStateChanges.iterator(InputFilesTaskStateChanges.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.CachingTaskStateChanges.reset(CachingTaskStateChanges.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.CachingTaskStateChanges.iterator(CachingTaskStateChanges.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.SummaryTaskStateChanges.firstDirtyIterator(SummaryTaskStateChanges.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.SummaryTaskStateChanges.access$000(SummaryTaskStateChanges.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.SummaryTaskStateChanges$1.computeNext(SummaryTaskStateChanges.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.SummaryTaskStateChanges$1.computeNext(SummaryTaskStateChanges.java:42)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
        at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.collectChangedMessages(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository$TaskArtifactStateImpl.isUpToDate(DefaultTaskArtifactStateRepository.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mohammad/superexnews/metro-bundler-symbolicate117830-24506-1aaqyox.dr9.sock (No such device or address)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.hash.DefaultHasher.hash(DefaultHasher.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileSnapshotter.snapshot(CachingFileSnapshotter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultVisitedTree$1.transform(DefaultVisitedTree.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultVisitedTree$1.transform(DefaultVisitedTree.java:104)
        at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:188)
        at org.gradle.util.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:183)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultVisitedTree.createTreeSnapshot(DefaultVisitedTree.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultVisitedTree.maybeCreateSnapshot(DefaultVisitedTree.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter$1.run(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(AbstractFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.rules.AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.createSnapshot(AbstractFileSnapshotTaskStateChanges.java:55)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mohammad/superexnews/metro-bundler-symbolicate117830-24506-1aaqyox.dr9.sock (No such device or address)
        at org.gradle.internal.hash.HashUtil.createHash(HashUtil.java:34)
        ... 93 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.509 secs
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, so can anyone tell me what is going wrong/ how to fix this?

Let me know if you need more information as well

Comment: Did you follow all the steps showing [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) before bundling your app?

Answer (score 31):

Fixed it by removing `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm install` command.

Answer (score 10):

I was also suffering through this error. What I found that in App > android 
folder there is a file which name is "metro-bundler-symbolicate117830-24506-1aaqyox.dr9.sock".
I delete this file and run

```
  ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

and it run successfully.

Answer (score 6):

I once had this error.
What I did was clean gradle, re-install npm and that was it.
See steps below:

```
cd android
gradlew clean
npm install
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command if you are on Linux.

```
sudo rm -R metro-symbolicate118829-8699-1t3awul.3lw9.sock
```

Or just delete all metro related files, some files cannot be deleted so you need to delete it as an Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue so i just cleaned the clean the gradle
`cd android`
`gradlew clean`
and it worked like a charm.

Can't comment cause of low reputation so please no negative voting :)